# Why doesn't electric field pass through an infinite grounded conducting sheet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors, method-of-images

[image]

Consider the diagram. Why doesn't the electric field cross the infinite conducting sheet. I understand if it was a closed conductor, the electric field inside would be 0 due to the electric field induced inside the conductor. But why is it so in this case? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

There can be no electric field inside a conductor otherwise the mobile change carriers within the conductor would move.

All of the electric field lines from the charge causing induction which reach the grounded conductor would end up on induced charges of the opposite sign on the surface of the conductor.
No electric field lines would enter the conductor so on the other side of the constructor, at the bottom of your diagram, there would be no evidence that there is a charge present that there is a charges present at the top of the conductor and in the region above it.

Comment: Thank you. So field lines can't pass through conducting surfaces, even though they're open? And if the conducting surface was finite here, some field lines bend around it?

Comment: And why won't there be electric field at the bottom of the diagram due to the charges induced in the conductor?

Comment: @SrijanDas Because the conductor is grounded.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please answer the first comment too?

Comment: @SrijanDas if the sheet was finite some of the field lines would bypass it.

Comment: Yes, some field lines would go by, it depends of the diameter of the area and the distance of the point charge.